# How do I generate an I²C clock with these specs?

Tags: vhdl, clock

[I2C clock specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K9wL.png) the clock from fpga is 100MHz and I need to run it at 400kHz, so in order to make 400kHz clock, I divided 100MHz/(2^8)=390625(close to 400kHz)(please tell me a more optimal way for clock dividers) here 8 is the no. of bits, so I made a counter(8 downto 0) and took its 8th(index) bit as my clock for the i2c communication process(vhdl).
please guide me as to how I can generate the required clock.
thank you

```
signal count:std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal sign:std_logic;
process(clk,rst)
begin
 if rst='1' then
 count<=(others=>'0');
 elsif rising_edge(clk) and rst='0' then 
 count<=count+1;
 end if;
 sign<=count(8);
end process;
```

Comment: Note that if you generate your clock from some kind of logic (like in the answer you accepted) there are chances that you will see errors during synthesis. A clock is not like any logic signal. I needs special care. In many FPGAs it must be generated by a specific device (PLL, clock generator...) and/or go through specific buffers, such that its electrical characteristics are compatible with its clock role. So, watch your error/warning messages and, if you encounter clock-related issues, open your FPGA's documentation and search for "clock" or "clock generator" or "clock manager".

Comment: In a Xilinx FPGA, for instance, you will probably need to replace your custom logic clock generator by a properly configured Digital Clock Manager (DCM) Module that takes your 100MHz clock as input and generates a 400kHz clock from it. This generated clock can then be routed to a clock network with clock buffers and be used as a regular clock by the other parts of your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just divide the clk by 250 to get a 400kHz clk. Something along the lines of:

```
signal count : integer range 0 to 250;
signal clk400 : std_logic; 
process (clk100, rst)
begin 
    if rst ='1' then 
        count  <= 0;
        clk400 <= '0'; 
    elsif rising_edge(clk100) then
       count <= count +1;
       if count = 249 then 
           count  <= 0;
           clk400 <= not clk400;
       end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Or, depending on you FPGA and tools, you could use a PLL.

Comment: please suggest how i can generate this 400khz clock with 1.3us clock low time and 0.6us clock high time. thankyou for your time(more details in the picture)

Comment: you dont need to, those are just minimum values. 50/50 duty cycle will do.

Comment: sir,apart from this, i want to know , are vhdl and verilog enough for a rtl designer or do i need to learn more languages ,i am a fresher in this field.